# How to return value from JavascriptExecutor.executeScript() method in java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written one method in java file and calling one method which is written in java script file with the help `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor` from that java file method. here is the code snippet:

```
public void validateFilename() {
    JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    jsExec.executeScript("getFileName();");
}


function() {
    window.getFileName = function() {
        var fileName = "sampleFile.txt";
        return fileName;
    }
};
```

I am able to call method `getFileName()` from java file but I am able to get the value of file name. If I give `alert(fileName)` it is showing fileName but not able to return that method in java file.

Is there any way to return the value from js file to java file with the help of API of selenium  **JavascriptExecutor**?

Comment: Just curious,.. Why wrap `getFileName` in an IIFE to then assign it to the `window`?

Answer (score 3):

`JavascriptExecutor.executeScript("<javascript code>")` allows you to execute JavaScript code, but when the code you pass to executeScript returns a value, Selenium won't know what the exact return type is at run time as JavaScript can return anything like `Number`, `String`, `Array`, `Object` etc.

To handle all return types, `executeScript` returns an object of 'Object' class which in turn can handle any return type of JavaScript. We can typecast the object returned to any one of following  supported objects:

- For an HTML element in js return, this method returns a `WebElement`
- For a decimal, a `Double` is returned
- For a non-decimal number, a `Long` is returned
- For a boolean, a `Boolean` is returned
- For all other cases, a `String` is returned.
- For an array, return a `List<Object>` with each object following the rules above.
- For a map, return a `Map<String, Object>` with values following the rules above.
  Unless the value is null or there is no return value, in which null is returned

Comment: This answers the question well, but has slightly shaky grammar. I've submitted some suggested edits which make it easier to read. I think this should be the accepted answer. I think it introduces and summarises the Java Selenium docs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to String when trying to get the response. Something like this:

```
String fileName = (String) jsExec.executeScript("return getFileName();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
jsExec.executeScript( "return getFileName()");
```

Comment: I tried this Object o= jsExec.executeScript( "return getFileName()"); but getting null value over there

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
 String txt = "return document.title";
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 String res = (String)js.executeScript(txt);
```